# Drag n drop in block area

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, drag-and-drop, draggable

I ran into this problem and don't know how to solve it. I need to drag and drop a point inside the map and save its new coordinates relative to the map.

Let's say I have a layout like in the picture I've attached. How can I get information about exactly where x or y in relation to this map I moved the element? I really need help!

I'm using HTML Drag And Drop, but I don't understand how to use the data that the event gives me to calculate this[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I found a solution. My code turned out like this. This way I keep the position of my points within my map!

P.S. I used Vue.js. Hope it's can help somebody.

```
<div class="map">
  <div>
      <img :src="props.currentItem.map_image" alt="Map" />
    </div>
    <div
      @drop.prevent="onDrop($event)"
      @dragenter.prevent
      @dragover.prevent
      class="map__container map__dropzone"
    >
      <map-item
        v-for="item in itemsData"
        :class="[`item-${item.id}`, { editable: props.isEditMapMode }]"
        :key="item.id"
        draggable
        @dragstart="startDrag($event, sensor)"
      />
  </div>
</div>

const offsetX = ref(0);
const offsetY = ref(0);

const startDrag = (event: DragEvent, item: IItemInterface) => {
  const rect = (event.target as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect();

  offsetX.value = event.clientX - rect.x;
  offsetY.value = event.clientY - rect.y;

  if (event.dataTransfer) {
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    event.dataTransfer.setData('itemId', item.id.toString());
  }
};

const onDrop = (event: DragEvent) => {
  const dropZoneRect = (event.target as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect();
  const left = dropZoneRect.left;
  const top = dropZoneRect.top;

  const itemId = event.dataTransfer?.getData('itemId');
  const item = document.querySelector(`.item-${itemId}`);

  (sensor as HTMLElement).style.left =
    event.clientX - left - offsetX.value + 'px';

  (sensor as HTMLElement).style.top =
    event.clientY - top - offsetY.value + 'px';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need *x and y* informations, in the event, you have x and y properties.
For example :

```js
function dodrop(event) {
  var dt = event.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  var count = files.length;
  output("File Count: " + count + "\n");

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log(event);
    output(" File " + i + ":\n(" + (typeof files[i]) + ") : <" + files[i] + " > " +
      files[i].name + " " + files[i].size + "\n");
  }
}

function output(text) {
  document.getElementById("output").textContent += text;
  //dump(text);
}
```

```html
<div id="output" style="min-height: 200px; white-space: pre; border: 1px solid black;" ondragenter="document.getElementById('output').textContent = ''; event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();" ondragover="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();"
  ondrop="event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();
     dodrop(event);">
  DROP FILES HERE FROM FINDER OR EXPLORER
</div>
```

**Then, look in the Console for (event).**

All these informations are explained in the doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Hope this helps you.

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand how I can calculate to what point in the height of the map the element has moved. For example, it was positioned absolute with a dependency on the map, its coordinates were x=20 y=20, I moved it 10px down, how do I calculate that I moved it exactly 10px relative to this map?